# Route::delete not responding in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am deleting a record but Route:delete not responding.I have another GET/POST which is in same File that is working fine.

**Route File**: Api\V1_0\Settings\MeasurementUnits\Routes\Measurement.php

(1) Used this.

```
use ERP\Api\V1_0\Settings\MeasurementUnits\Controllers\MeasurementController;
use ERP\Support\Interfaces\RouteRegistrarInterface;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Registrar as RegistrarInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

(2) Route:delete

```
//delete data -- delete request
    Route::delete('Settings/MeasurementUnits/Measurement/{measurementUnitId}', 'Settings\MeasurementUnits\Controllers\MeasurementController@destroy');
```

**Controller File**: Api\V1_0\Settings\MeasurementUnits\Controllers\MeasurementController.php

```
 public function destroy(Request $request,$measurementUnitId)
{
    dd(" In Destroy--");
    exit;
}
```

I am Printing "In Destroy--" in Destroy Function but it's not Working.Even when i printing in my Route file (Routes\Measurement.php) its also not working. That all thinks are working on Another Method (GET/POST).

Also another thing is that when i Request it from Postman it give me Just Loading. Request not stop until i Manually Cancel that Request.

Thank You.

Comment: Try: Route::delete('Settings/MeasurementUnits/Measurement/{measurementUnitId}', ['uses' => 'Settings\MeasurementUnits\Controllers\MeasurementController@destroy']);

Comment: Not working :(.

Comment: try:
Route::resource('Settings/MeasurementUnits/Measurement', ['only' => ['destroy']]);

Comment: Also not working.

Comment: Route::delete('Settings/MeasurementUnits/Measurement/{measurementUnitId}', 'MeasurementController@destroy');

Comment: instead of echo and exit, use dd("In Destroy--"); also in your kernel.php file comment the VerifyCsrfToken in order to make Postman tests. Let us know what happens

Comment: Not working this -> Route::delete('Settings/MeasurementUnits/Measurement/{measurementUnitId}', 'MeasurementController@destroy');

Comment: I use dd("In Destroy--"); and Comment VerifyCsrfToken but also nothing happens.

Comment: if you use: Route::delete('Settings/MeasurementUnits/Measurement', 'Settings\MeasurementUnits\Controllers\MeasurementController'); it works on all methods but DELETE, is that right?

Comment: yes, it's not working for Delete only.

Comment: what URL are you using for the request?

Comment: Route::get , Route::post is working fine.. but Route:delete not working

Comment: http://[myDomain]/settings/measurement-units

Comment: I Changed "measurement-units" to "Measurement" from ROOT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php and ROOT\app\Api\V1_0\Support\RouteServiceProvider.php

Comment: comment the Route::get and Route::post and use only Route::resource, test all methods. When deleting shouldn't you also add the ID at the end of the URL, like http://[myDomain]/settings/measurement-units/123

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.2. Can i use implicit controller ?

Comment: not too sure about implicit controller but the Route::resource is compatible with laravel 5.2  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers

Comment: I Used Route::resource. but same problem occur. Delete request not responding.

Comment: You have not mentioned the most important part of the question - how are you accessing your `delete` route?  Show us your form, or whatever you are using to hit the route.

Comment: how are you sending a delete request?

Comment: Friends..its working...I don't know but how?... when i run on postman today its working now...I did't change in code or someone else..i tested more than 5-6 times but its still running good.  but if its occur next time or accidentally stop then how can i understand the problem..:(

Comment: Did you restart the server (or the apache)? that's the only thing that comes to my mind. When I face such problems what I do is always make things as simple as possible. In your case I'd cut that manual handling of "measurement-units" to "Measurement". Then I'd check the response in the own route file instead of calling the controller, something like Route::delete('route', function() { dd("delete"); }); But as it just worked by itself it's very hard to tell...I thought about cache, but I think Postman clears cache before any requests anyways...

Comment: yesterday, I restart my apache (using Xampp) but that time it was not working.but today when i open my project it's working.another thing was that when i printed something in my route files (direct in reguster()) its also not work for delete but work in POST/GET.